# How to read Data form BigQuery and File system using Apache beam python job in same pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-beam

I am trying to read some data from Bigquery and some data from file system using below code.

> ```
> apn = p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=apn_query, use_standard_sql=True)) | beam.combiners.ToList()
> preprocess_rows = p | beam.io.ReadFromText(file_path, coder=UnicodeCoder())
> ```

But when I run this pipeline, I am getting below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/etl/dataflow/etlTXLPreprocessor.py", line 125, in 
>       run()   File "/etl/dataflow/etlTXLPreprocessor.py", line 120, in run
>       p.run().wait_until_finish()   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 461, in run
>       self._options).run(False)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 474, in run
>       return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py",
>   line 182, in run_pipeline
>       return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py",
>   line 413, in run_pipeline
>       pipeline.replace_all(_get_transform_overrides(options))   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 443, in replace_all
>       self._replace(override)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 340, in _replace
>       self.visit(TransformUpdater(self))   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 503, in visit
>       self._root_transform().visit(visitor, self, visited)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 939, in visit
>       part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 939, in visit
>       part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 939, in visit
>       part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 942, in visit
>       visitor.visit_transform(self)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 338, in visit_transform
>       self._replace_if_needed(transform_node)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
>   line 301, in _replace_if_needed
>       new_output = replacement_transform.expand(input_node)   File "/etl/dataflow/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/sdf_direct_runner.py",
>   line 87, in expand
>       invoker = DoFnInvoker.create_invoker(signature, process_invocation=False)   File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line
>   360, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.create_invoker
>   TypeError: create_invoker() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1
>   given)

But If I run my code like this

> ```
> apn = p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=apn_query, use_standard_sql=True)) | beam.combiners.ToList()
> apn1 = p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=apn_query, use_standard_sql=True)) | beam.combiners.ToList()
> ```

**or** like this

> ```
> preprocess_rows = p | beam.io.ReadFromText(file_path, coder=UnicodeCoder())
> preprocess_rows1 = p | beam.io.ReadFromText(file_path, coder=UnicodeCoder())
> ```

I am unable to figure out the error.
Is It a limitation to read from the same data source in Apache beam pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error when performing the same type of action, pulling in data from BigQuery and the filesystem.

```
lines = p | "Read Input Parameters" >> ReadFromText(options.input)
past_posts = p | "Get Past Posts From BigQuery" >> Read(BigQuerySource(query=f"SELECT url FROM {full_bq_table_id}", use_standard_sql=False))
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/craigslist_pipeline.py", line 14, in 
>       full_bq_table_id=f"apartment-data-project:{dataset}.craigslist_posts"
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/pipeline/**init**.py", line 35, in run
>       result = p.run()
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 461, in run
>       self._options).run(False)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 474, in run
>       return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 182, in run_pipeline
>       return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 413, in run_pipeline
>       pipeline.replace_all(_get_transform_overrides(options))
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 443, in replace_all
>       self._replace(override)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 340, in _replace
>       self.visit(TransformUpdater(self))
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 503, in visit
>       self._root_transform().visit(visitor, self, visited)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 939, in visit
>       part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 939, in visit
>       part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 939, in visit
>       part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
>     [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 942, in visit
>       visitor.visit_transform(self)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 338, in visit_transform
>       self._replace_if_needed(transform_node)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 301, in _replace_if_needed
>       new_output = replacement_transform.expand(input_node)
>     File "/Users/ianmitchell/Documents/Personal Projects/Craigslist/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/sdf_direct_runner.py", line 87, in expand
>       invoker = DoFnInvoker.create_invoker(signature, process_invocation=False)
>     File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 360, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.create_invoker
>   TypeError: create_invoker() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)

Wondering why you cannot pull from different sources as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the direct runner in Apache Beam v2.19. The fix was done but not released, yet. Downgrade your apache-beam to 2.16 (pip install apache-beam==2.16) and it will work.